# Chat Timestamp on Message

Tags: php, html, timestamp

mHello, I have a CodeCanyon PHP Chat Network. I noticed that the chat's do no currently equip a timestamp system which displays the date of the message when it was entered.

I was researching online and I can't find something helpful, so I'm asking Stackoverflow!

How can I implement my own timestamp system to show the date when the message was submitted?

Comment: Hello, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing so far, I've been researching to see if there's a made up code already. But I'm not finding anything so far. Also, I don't have that great knowledge of PHP, Javascript, I'm more of HTML and CSS. The easy stuff.

Comment: What is `CodeCanyon PHP Chat Network`? Does it log to a DB? If so maybe add a default timestamp to each record.

Comment: Do ask @chris85 suggested.

Comment: I'm using OwlChat from CodeCanyon

Answer (score 0):

1. Enter the the Mysql database through phpmyadmin/different db managing tool.
2. Find the table with the message. a filed with with "time-stamp" type.
3. Add to the class that calls message from the db the time stamp field.
4. Add in the view the time stamp in the format inside html where you want.

This is a general direction to do what you want. If you will add the name of the chat system it will be easier to help you.

Comment: The chat system I purchased on CodeCanyon is OwlChat, I have very little knowledge of Databases stuff as well. Sorry